# Gfortran can't compile NumPy

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, fortran, gfortran

I'm working on a Raspberry-based project that needs SciPy, NumPy and scikit-learn. And we need to package our virtual environment in a .deb for distribution. For that, we use dh_virtualenv, which up until now has worked just fine.

When I just install our requirements on the venv, like so:

```
myvenv/bin/pip install numpy
myvenv/bin/pip install scipy
myvenv/bin/pip install sklearn
```

The dependencies install just fine, although they take a painfully long time to do so.

The problem comes when we try to make the package, following exactly these steps:

```
mkdir myvenv-0.1
cd myvenv-0.1
dh_make --createorig
nano ./debian/rules
```

Then I find the "dh $@" part in the editor and I replace it with this

```
%:
    dh $@ --with python-virtualenv --python /path/to/myvenv/bin/python
```

And then I edit `debian/control`:

```
nano ./debian/control
```

and fill it up thusly:

```
Source: myvenv
Maintainer: My Name <mymail@mymail.com>
Build-Depends: debhelper (>= 9)
Standards-Version: 3.9.5
Homepage: <insert the upstream URL, if relevant>

Package: myvenv
Version: 0.1-1
Architecture: armhf
Pre-Depends: dpkg (>= 1.16.1), python2.7 | python2.6
Section: python
Priority: extra
Description: My Description
```

Then I freeze my requirements:

```
/path/to/myvenv/bin/pip freeze > requirements.txt
```

nano into them:

```
nano requirements.txt
```

Then I look for the myvenv requirement line and remove it, otherwise the venv requires itself, which breaks the whole procedure later on (I know this too well.)

At this point I generate a setup.py file for the myvenv package, which has to implement a fake unit test command, because dh_virtualenv tries to run the unit tests by default and the flag to disable them just doesn't work. Here's the file:

```
from distutils.core import setup
from distutils.cmd import Command


class TestCommand(Command):
  user_options=[]
  description = ''
  def initialize_options(self):
    pass

  def finalize_options(self):
    pass

  def run(self):
    self.announce('test')


setup(
      cmdclass={
             'test': TestCommand
      },
      name='myvenv',
      version='0.1',
      description='desc')
```

Then I export the path onto which myvenv needs to be installed:

```
export DH_VIRTUALENV_INSTALL_ROOT=/path/
```

At last, I can build the package, but I need to commit first, so I do

```
dpkg-source --commit
```

I give my patch literally any name and press enter, then I:

```
dpkg-buildpackage -us -uc
```

This procedure has worked so well until now I have a python class that does this automatically.

The libraries also install just fine on the venv itself.

But, for whatever reason, packaging the virtualenv just causes gfortran to blow up.

The error traceback is huge, it basically ends like this:

```
  File "/path/to/myvenv-0.1/debian/myvenv/path/to/myvenv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/setuptools/command/easy_install.py", line 1066, in run_setup

    raise DistutilsError("Setup script exited with %s" % (v.args[0],))

distutils.errors.DistutilsError: Setup script exited with error: Command "/usr/bin/gfortran -Wall -g -Wl,-z,relro build/temp.linux-armv7l-3.4/numpy/linalg/lapack_litemodule.o build/temp.linux-armv7l-3.4/numpy/linalg/lapack_lite/python_xerbla.o -L/usr/lib/atlas-base/atlas -L/usr/lib/atlas-base -L/usr/lib/gcc/arm-linux-gnueabihf/4.9 -L/usr/lib/gcc/arm-linux-gnueabihf/4.9 -Lbuild/temp.linux-armv7l-3.4 -llapack -lf77blas -lcblas -latlas -lf77blas -lcblas -lgfortran -o build/lib.linux-armv7l-3.4/numpy/linalg/lapack_lite.cpython-34m.so" failed with exit status 1



----------------------------------------
Cleaning up...
Command python setup.py egg_info failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-ouvtjhcw/scipy
Storing debug log for failure in /home/admin/.pip/pip.log
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/dh_virtualenv", line 85, in <module>
    sys.exit(main() or 0)
  File "/usr/bin/dh_virtualenv", line 67, in main
    deploy.install_dependencies()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/dh_virtualenv/deployment.py", line 112, in install_dependencies
    subprocess.check_call(self.pip('-r', requirements_path))
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 540, in check_call
    raise CalledProcessError(retcode, cmd)
subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['debian/myvenv/path/to/myvenv/bin/python', 'debian/myvenv/path/to/myvenv/bin/pip', 'install', '--log=/tmp/tmpRjP02B', '-r', './requirements.txt']' returned non-zero exit status 1
debian/rules:22: recipe for target 'binary' failed
make: *** [binary] Error 1
dpkg-buildpackage: error: fakeroot debian/rules binary gave error exit status 2
```

Further up it said it was installing lapack_lite. Sorry I had to restart my computer and it takes a very long time to run this again. I only kept the last part for further web-searching (which has turned up nothing thus far.)

Platform is Raspbian. Also Python is version 3.4.4. Pip is version 1.5.6

### Update

After 45 minutes of pure bliss I have another log. I have the entire thing. It's so huge I had to [put it on pastebin](https://pastebin.com/7g6FLmPB), in fact.

Comment: Does the traceback include the actual error from the `gfortran` invocation? Without that, it’s hard to know whether the problem is that you haven’t installed gfortran, or its too old, or your install is broken, or there’s something causing it to be invoked wrong, or what.

Comment: yes, third line of the traceback. btw it IS installed, I tried running it. I also did apt-get install libblas-dev liblapack-dev g++

Comment: Yeah, but that’s just the exit code from the script that drives the gfortran call. Is the error output of gfortran, or at least of the script, not included anywhere above that in the huge traceback output that you truncated?

Comment: If none of that is printed anywhere, or in a log file, you’re going to have to figure out how to get things expanded to the point where you can run the same gfortran invocation manually, which is a lot more work to get the same info.

Comment: I'm running this again so I'll have a new traceback in a while. I'll update my post when I do.

Comment: Could you run the same `gfortran` command line exactly as it is shown and see/tell us what errors are?

Comment: There you go, now you have the traceback.

Comment: I just noticed there's no mention of any gfortran error. I wonder if it's because the output was split between the file and the command line, so maybe it's logged differently or something. I'm running out of time so I can't run this again.... if you see something that is blatantly obvious for someone who knows more about fortran and/or numpy please let me know....

Comment: I think I have a lead: https://github.com/spotify/dh-virtualenv/issues/85

Comment: I'll tell you guys how this works on Monday.

Comment: It would be worth synopsising the new stack trace in the question, since relying on an external pasteboard would make the question off-topic. We have this guideline because external links break quite frequently, leaving the site with a question that cannot be understood by future readers, and leaving volunteers to clean it up. Would you extract the most useful messages from that log data and paste that into the question? I think it's OK to add the link in addition to that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TL;DR: Use piwheels.

I have suffered a lot trying to solve this and basically I had given up until I found piwheels.

It's reasonably up to date, maybe youll get scipy 1.0.0 instead of 1.0.1 but really, who cares.
It'll also substantially reduce the time it takes to package your venv.

Simply override dh_virtualenv in your debian/rules file, like so:

```
[...]
override_dh_virtualenv:
    dh_virtualenv --python /path/to/myvenv/bin/python -v --extra-index-url https://www.piwheels.org/simple
%:
[...]
```